# Rundeck global variable in meta job not resolved

Tags: rundeck

we have a Rundeck (3.1.2-20190927) job which triggers multiple other jobs in Rundeck. In the /etc/rundeck/framework.properties are global variables defined that are used in the jobs. It's used to build the url of our Icinga so Rundeck can submit th job result to the monitoring. The variable is used in the notifications tab (edit job -> notification) of every single job.
When the meta job has run, it submits the result successfully to the monitoring. The same applies to the 'sub' job, if you trigger them manualy. BUT if they are triggert by the meta job, they throw an error:

`Error calling the endpoint: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://icinga-master-${globals.environment}.some.domain.`

It looks like the global variable is not resolved correctly when the job are triggert by the meta job. Strange to say, other meta jobs don't have this problem. I can't find any configuration differences. Has anybody an idea what the cause could be?
Thanks for any help!

Update: Here's my job definition

```
- defaultTab: output
  description: "Call Patchday Jobs in a row  \n**Attention! This will reboot the servers**"
  executionEnabled: true
  group: CloudServices/SomeSoftWare
  id: 5cf2966c-3e5f-4a32-8cce-b3e82b6fd036
  loglevel: INFO
  multipleExecutions: true
  name: Patchday SomeSoftWare - Meta Job
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'tags: role_SomeSoftWare'
  nodesSelectedByDefault: false
  notification:
    onfailure:
      plugin:
        configuration:
          _noSSLVerification: ''
          _printResponseToFile: ''
          _proxySettings: ''
          authentication: Basic
          body: |-
            {
              "type": "Service",
              "filter": "service.name==\"Rundeck-Job - ${job.name}\"",
              "exit_status": 2,
              "plugin_output": "'${job.name}' failed"
            }
          contentType: application/json
          file: ''
          headers: 'Accept: application/json'
          method: POST
          noSSLVerification: 'true'
          oauthTokenEndpoint: ''
          oauthValidateEndpoint: ''
          password: ******
          proxyIP: ''
          proxyPort: ''
          remoteUrl: https://icinga-master-${globals.environment}.some.domain:5665/v1/actions/process-check-result
          timeout: '30000'
          username: rundeck_process-check-result
        type: HttpNotification
    onsuccess:
      plugin:
        configuration:
          _noSSLVerification: ''
          _printResponseToFile: ''
          _proxySettings: ''
          authentication: Basic
          body: |-
            {
              "type": "Service",
              "filter": "service.name==\"Rundeck-Job - ${job.name}\"",
              "exit_status": 0,
              "plugin_output": "'${job.name}' succeeded"
            }
          contentType: application/json
          file: ''
          headers: 'Accept: application/json'
          method: POST
          noSSLVerification: 'true'
          oauthTokenEndpoint: ''
          oauthValidateEndpoint: ''
          password: ******
          proxyIP: ''
          proxyPort: ''
          remoteUrl: https://icinga-master-${globals.environment}.some.domain:5665/v1/actions/process-check-result
          timeout: '30000'
          username: rundeck_process-check-result
        type: HttpNotification
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
  options:
  - description: Addition paramater to give to the ansible-playbook call
    name: AdditionalParameter
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - jobref:
        args: 'branch: ${globals.defaultbranch}'
        group: Infrastructure
        name: Icinga Service Downtime
        nodefilters:
          dispatch:
            nodeIntersect: true
        uuid: 6eec5749-ef35-481e-aea8-674f233c32ac
    - description: Pause Bamboo Server
      jobref:
        args: -branch ${globals.defaultbranch} -bamboo_command pause
        group: Infrastructure
        name: Bamboo Control
        nodefilters:
          dispatch:
            nodeIntersect: true
        uuid: 87bc7f1c-d133-4d7e-9df9-2b40fb935fd4
    - configuration:
        ansible-become: 'false'
        ansible-disable-limit: 'false'
        ansible-playbook-inline: |
          - name: +++ Stop Tomcat ++++
            hosts: tag_role_SomeSoftWare
            gather_facts: true
            remote_user: ec2-user
            become: yes

            tasks:
              - name: stop tomcat
                service:
                  name: tomcat
                  state: stopped
      nodeStep: false
      type: com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowStep
    - description: SomeSoftWare Update
      jobref:
        args: -branch ${globals.defaultbranch}
        group: Infrastructure
        name: SomeSoftWare Server - Setup
        nodefilters:
          dispatch:
            nodeIntersect: true
        uuid: f01a4483-d8b2-43cf-99fd-6a610d25c3a4
    - description: Install/Update fs-cli
      jobref:
        args: -branch ${globals.defaultbranch}
        group: Infrastructure
        name: firstspirit-cli - Setup
        nodefilters:
          dispatch:
            nodeIntersect: true
        uuid: c7c54433-be96-4d85-b2c1-32d0534b5c60
    - description: Install/Update Modules
      jobref:
        args: -branch ${globals.defaultbranch}
        group: Infrastructure
        name: SomeSoftWare Modules - Setup
        nodefilters:
          dispatch:
            nodeIntersect: true
        uuid: f7a8929b-2bc3-4abe-8c69-e0d2acf62159
    - description: restart SomeSoftWare
      exec: sudo service SomeSoftWare restart
    - description: Resume Bamboo Server
      jobref:
        args: -branch ${globals.defaultbranch} -bamboo_command resume
        group: Infrastructure
        name: Bamboo Control
        nodefilters:
          dispatch:
            nodeIntersect: true
        uuid: 87bc7f1c-d133-4d7e-9df9-2b40fb935fd4
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  timeZone: Europe/Berlin
  uuid: 5cf2966c-3e5f-4a32-8cce-b3e82b6fd036
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share a Minimal Reproducible Example (Rundeck Job Definition in this case) to take a look? Thanks!

Comment: I've added the job definition

Comment: Thanks! Just to discard: which Java version do you have? You can see that doing: java -version

Comment: We're using 1.8_202.

Comment: Can you try calling the child jobs options arguments with "-branch: ${globals.defaultbranch}" instead of "branch: ${globals.defaultbranch}" (without quotes, note that i added "-" character at beginning). If you see the first step in your job definiton you're calling it with "branch: ${globals.defaultbranch}"

Comment: globals.defaultbranch is working. The only variable that's not is {globals.environment}. But only in this constellation. As mentioned, when running one of the jobs for itself, it's resolved.

Comment: Update: I started a job, that is affected by this issue, with debug output. The variable is definitely set:
`RD_GLOBALS_ENVIRONMENT=dev`
So, it is not passed correctly to the Ansible playbook. For now I can't tell what the root cause is, but I'm trying to further look into it.

Comment: As it turns out, there are also "not meta jobs" affected. RD_GLOBALS_ENVIRONMENT is set, but is not replaced by it's values in the job run. Wether in the Ansible playbook that is started nor in the other node steps in this job.